# OpenSource Report Designer for user runtime report design?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, report

I need to include a report designer into my WPF C#.NET application so that the user can edit and execute reports an runtime. The best way would be opensource. I have read some older discussions but haven´t find anything useable. Is there any solution right now?
Thank for your advice.
Regards,
Radek

Comment: I'm also curious if there is a free report designer, but I assume, that only simple report tools are available for free ;-).

Answer (score 5):

This list is somewhat more recent: http://opensource.com/business/14/6/three-open-source-business-tools

Brit: http://eclipse.org/birt/

Penthao: http://community.pentaho.com/projects/reporting/

Jaspar: http://community.jaspersoft.com/ (Though it's Community and Commercial version)

NextReports Designer is free: http://www.next-reports.com/index.php/products/nextreports-designer.html

Here is one that I found http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9772/Report-Generator though it's a bit older

Open Source RDL: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9260/Project-RDL-Open-Source-Report-Definition-Language

And one with a Designer: http://www.fyireporting.com/products.html